# Get current page title without loop

Tags: php, title

I have a small script which should get the meta title of the current page the script is added into. The problem is, that its working fine on several test pages, but not into my CMS. It loops until death there and I cant reach any page on my server until I restart apache completely and by taking the script off.

May someone take a look at it? This would be really awesome since I used google for hours and sure, I found X threads and pages, but never a solution for this special loop-effect.

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['ignore']))
{
    $url = curPageURL();
    $data = implode("", file("$url?ignore=this"));
    preg_match ("/<title>([^`]*?)<\/title>/", $data, $match);
    $urltitle = $match[1];
}
?>
<?echo $urltitle;?>
```

Comment: What does "it loops until death" mean? You will have to debug what is going on, we cannot guess that... What requests are done= What do the logs say?

Comment: Amend your code to include the loop that's causing your grief, it sounds like you've got a bad conditional that's causing the infinite loop.

Comment: Also, you never check whether or not your call to `file()` is successful or not, and using file-based functions to retrieve data over HTTP is always a bad idea IMHO. Use [cURL](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php). I know it's awkward compared to file operations, but it's much more tolerant of weird crap that happens during an HTTP session, and can properly report specific errors rather than just returning `false`.

Comment: Why are you even making a request to the page you are on? shouldn't the page already know the title of itself?

Answer (score 3):

The `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` can also include GET params like this:

```
mysite.com?param1=1&param2=2
```

Then you try to append a string `?ignore=this` so you get

```
mysite.com?param1=1&param2=2?ignore=this
```

which is translated by PHP into variables like

```
param1 = '1'
param2 = '2?ignore=this'
```

You must check for `?` symbol in the $url variable

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function to get the current page url :

```
function currentURL() {
    $protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], 'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
    $host     = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $port     = $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
    $query    = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $protocol.'://'.$host.($port != 80 ? ':'.$port : '').$query;
}
```

But your problem comes from here :

```
if (!isset($_GET['ignore']))
{
    $url = curPageURL();
    $data = implode("", file("$url?ignore=this"));
    /* ... */
}
```

This will work with "test pages", but you CMS propably use url-rewriting, which **can** cause the lost of your `$_GET['ignore']` variable : if you've already other GET variable for example.
You should have a look into your `.htaccess` files, or read your CMS documentation to know what can change you url.

Anyway, it seems you're building some unstable code, and this only to get the page title. I'm pretty sure you've got another way to get it easily with your CMS.